Building a database where novels can have many chapters, but also new chapters
I'm building a website for novels, where each novel has chapters, but you can refresh the novel to get the latest chapters. There also a page to show the latest updates from your library novels.
When ever you view a novel, it get saved to the database with all the chapter's metadata except the chapter's content, so when you visit the saved novel again, you get the saved novel without fetching for the novel.
The question is do I make a separate table updated_chapters for the the latest chapters? Or make an empty updated_at column in the chapters table that is null and only updated chapters has it as date?
The separate table approach diagram: dbDiagram
The chapters updated_at approach diagram: dbDiagram

Is this a single user application?  Otherwise, the information of which user has read up to which chapter of any book needs its own separate table...  (Your second diagram also has the direction of the 1-to-many relationships inverted, and that structure is not correct nor it is enough anyway: but making requirements precise here is a prerequisite.  E.g. "update" is usually a modification, so the very phrasing here should be made more precise.)

The user_id column as with many columns that aren't required to understand the problem has been omitted from the novel table,  I missed that inverted relationship as I posted the question quite late on my time, sorry.

I could use updated_chapters instead of updates.
Do you recommand this approach or do I use just a column in the chapters table?
